# Obter o mesmo valor de uma subtração no Arduino com Python

Tags: python

O seguinte codigo no arduino produz o valor 26.

```
int a = 32760;
int b = -32750;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(b-a); 
}
```

Eu gostaria de enviar esses dois valores via serial para um script python (Serial.println(String(a)) e Serial.println(String(b))) e obter o mesmo valor da subtração com o python

Eu acredito que devo usar a biblioteca python  Struct com o formato signed short, porem não sei exatamente como fazer isso.

Comment: Não faça agradecimentos e não faça cumprimentos nas publicações. Veja  [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), veja também [Saudações e Agradecimentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%c3%a7%c3%b5es-e-agradecimentos) e veja os comentários de [Edições apenas para remover saudações/agradecimentos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2704/edi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-apenas-para-remover-sauda%c3%a7%c3%b5es-agradecimentos)

Comment: Minha sugestão é enviar como ASCII, ou mesmo como estrutura JSON, para o Python. Lidar com formatos binários é encrenca. A pergunta também está muito ampla, é sobre Python mas contém código Arduino... a pergunta correta teria um exemplo em Python tentado fazer unpacking de um valor binário a partir de uma string ou byte array, sem envolver a questão da comunicação entre Arduino e computador. Ser desenvolvedor é saber quebrar um problema em problemas menores.

Answer (score 1):

conforme: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614950/how-to-convert-a-number-to-signed-short-in-python

No python  para se obter o mesmo valor no resultado basta limitar em 16bits o resultado da subtração, algo como:

```
result = (int(b) - int(a)) & 0xffff
```